# Node on Windows error: "Source Path Too Long"

Tags: node.js, windows, node-modules

**Explanation :**
There are about 15 subfolders in the `node_modules` directory. When going to perform any operation (deleted, moved or renamed) it popup below message.

**Error message:**

> The source file name(s) are larger than is supported by the file
> system. Try moving to a location which has a shorter path name, or try
> renaming to shorter name(s) before attempting this operation.

**Screenshot :**
[image]

sub folder inside **`npm_modules`** directory.

> node_modules\gulp-connect\node_modules\gulp-util\node_modules\dateformat\node_modules\meow\node_modules\normalize-package-data\node_modules\validate-npm-package-license\node_modules\spdx-expression-parse\node_modules\spdx-license-ids\spdx-license-ids.json

**Tried so far:**

I also tried to delete the folder (node_modules) using command prompt using command `rmdir <dirname> /S` but did not work as well.

[image]

There is a way to do this is that go into subfolder after subfolder, renaming each folder to something short like 'b'. Eventually the path is short enough to allow deletion. This will waste quite a bit of time.

Is there any efficient way to delete this `node_modules` directory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Error Deleting node\_modules Folder: Source Path Too Long](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35632789/windows-error-deleting-node-modules-folder-source-path-too-long)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Newest versions of `npm` fix this issue flattening the path: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3697.

Try

```
D:\vms\fe> robocopy d:\path\to\temp\dir node_modules /purge
```

to remove the nested dirs.

**Update**

As pointed by [Coding Professor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37145805/windows-error-source-path-too-long/37145909?noredirect=1#comment61870156_37145909), another option is use [rimraf](https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf) util (which basically calls `rm -rf`):

```
> npm install -g rimraf
> rimraf node_modules
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. can you add this command also `npm install -g rimraf` then run `rimraf node_modules` from there the folder hierarchy should be able to be deleted.Its also working fine.It will be more useful for the users to choose any of the solution.Then i will mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, and because of the release of a newish [open-source project](https://github.com/Microsoft/winfile) released by Microsoft, you can easily delete paths that are too long  using [WinFile](https://github.com/Microsoft/winfile) (which was introduced in WinXP). 
Sometimes you have to go "Back to the Future". This can delete paths too long on Microsoft networks share as well.

[image]

WinFile (compiled for Win10) available here https://github.com/Microsoft/winfile

To find many paths that are too long and automate a fix, I recommend [Path Too Long Auto Fixer](https://pathtoolongautofixer.blogspot.com/) - a free demo is available.